# Android Dev Q Regarding Permission Request

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, android-permissions

**Hey all!**

So as Android Devs know, Android M introduced a new Permissions system.. I am nearing the end stages of Coding my App, and implementing this Permission Request is one of my final tasks. I just have a few quick questions about the way it works..

Upon starting my App for the first time, the user see's a Welcome screen, with a view pager type of interface with 4 pages containing information about using the App.. The last page will explain to the user that the App needs a Permission to be granted in order to use the App, and upon clicking a "Lets get Started" Button, I will have the Permission Request pop up..

**Here are my Questions:**

**(1)** - Am I actually able to Request the Permission on the fly like I descibed above, to be used later at some point, before I actually need to use the Permission? or am I limited to Requesting the Permission at specific times, such as when I actually need it, or at runtime, etc..?

**(2)** - Once the user Grants the Permission I Request, is it permanent? or will I need to Request Permission yet again if for example they reboot their phone etc?


**Huge thanks for the information!**

Answer (score 0):

1. You can request for Marshmallow permissions at any point of time, they are not limited.
2. Yes, once the user grants the permission it is permanent, so no pop up will need to be generated. Although the user will still be able to manually remove the permission from the Settings app, which will require you to ask for it again next time you'll need it.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the info, perfectly answered!